# me/albums return data nil facebook swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i develop an app which take users albums and photos from facebook and show them in app.

I use custom button:

```
@objc func loginButtonClicked() {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in!")
            self.getFBUserData()
        }
    }
}
```

if login success i call another method which request albums

```
func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil) {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/albums", parameters: nil).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                print("result = \(result)")
                let responseDictionary = JSON(result)
                if let data = responseDictionary["data"].array {
                    print("data result = \(data)")
                    print("----------")
                    for i in 0..<data.count {
                        print(data[i])
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

the printed result is

```
result = Optional({
    data =     (
    );
})
```

if i will change request from "me/albums" to "me" i will take some info that won't be nil. Have anybody any ideas?

Comment: Have you allowed your app to access your photos?

Comment: i am administrator in my facebook app(if u about that). This role give permissions to the photos(maybe) )

Comment: No, the app admin has to grant the app permissions the same way every other user does, there is no access to anything granted automatically.